# Нужно сделать двумерный массив структур для вывода данных на терминал

Tags: c

Мне нужно выводить данные на терминал. Для этого нужно знать позицию `y, x` и атрибуты код символа, цвет символа, цвет заднего фона символа. По сути это укладывается в трехмерный массив вида
`char DISP1[2][30][95];` но очень не удобно обращаться к коду символа, цвету, цвету фона. Охота сделать двухмерный массив структур где два первых байта будут описаны в виде

```
struct{
char ch;
char B_COLOR : 4;
char F_COLOR : 4;
} atSymbol;
```

а остальные данные это позиция `Y,X.`
Сделал вот так:

```
atSymbol[30][95] где 30 это Y, 95 это X.
```

В силу своих незнаний данная структура не работает.

Comment: "Не работает" - это не информация. "Велосипед не едет" может включать как пробитое колесо, так и разломанную надвое раму... Покажите, *что именно* у вас не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> struct{
> char ch;
> char B_COLOR : 4;
> char F_COLOR : 4;
> } atSymbol;
> ```

Это определение переменной с именем `atSymbol` и типом `struct { ... }`. Чтобы определить тип нужно сделать:

```
struct atSymbol {
  // ...
};

// ...

struct atSymbol foo[30][95];
```

или

```
typedef struct {
  // ...
} atSymbol;

// ...

atSymbol foo[30][95];
```

---

Или можно сразу определить весь массив:

```
struct {
  // ...
} atSymbol[30][95];
```